# How to implement token based api for rest api in java?

Tags: java, apache, token

I am working on a project, and I came here in this moment, where I now need authorization. I am using Apache Shiro for my web interface, but as long as mobile web-apps are concerned, I hardly think basic username:password auth will hold. And, the documentation of Shiro doesn't say much  about tokens. Therefore, as the alternative, I am thinking to implement token.

I came upon few ideas.

1.To use Oauth, but it sounds too complicated.

2.To use JWT. This sounds fascinating.

So, after some research, and based upon ease of use, I opted to use JWT. But, I came across some questions.

1. While reading online, I saw Authorization header decorated with "Bearer ". What does Bearer do? As far as I have understood, "Bearer has something to do with Oauth, as googling Bearer mostly comes with "Oauth" on it.
2. However, I decided to put this header to the response, "Authorization" : "Bearer ".
3. Now what, how will jax-rs figure out itself. Do I need to implement my own methods to deal with authorization, or there are some filters or frameworks that deals with all these so I can focus on what I can do.

Comment: Sorry but product recommendations are prohibited on this site. You should probably ask that part on another site?

Answer (score 1):

Bearer means that possessing the token (ie: being the bearer of the token) is sufficient to be authorized. You don't need to prove you hold a private key or something else.